# ExtJS 6 chart legend event listeners don't work

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic

Here is the fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1b7d

Main idea is that legend code below does not work. Event listeners don't work.

```
legend: {
  docked: 'bottom',
     listeners: {
        selectionchange: function(me, selected) {
            alert("1");
        },
        select: function( me, record, index, eOpts ) {
            alert("2");
        },
        activate: function( me ) {
            alert("3");
        },
        show: function( me ) {
            alert("4");
        }
    },
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the four you mentioned, I guess they are leftovers from the class hierarchy, and are not fired from xtype legend. Or it's a bug, you could ask in the sencha forum.

I can assure you that the `boxready` and the `itemclick` event are fired correctly.

Comment: Right, these 2 events work. Others don't, seems to be a bug

Answer (score 1):

This is still an issue in 7.3.1.  The below listeners still dont fire

```
    {
      xtype: "polar",
      legend: {
        docked: "bottom",
        listeners: {
          viewready: "onViewReady",
          itemclick: "onItemClick",
        }
      },
      // hidden for brevity
    }
```